# Too much String parameters in method

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style, checkstyle, pmd

Sometimes, I have the problem with one PMD check about my code. I mean - too much String parameters:

"Rather than using a lot of String arguments, consider using a container object for those values"

f.e.:

```
public void printPersons (final String name, final String surname, final String day, final String car, final String city, final String petName) 
{

}
```

How You can avoid that situation in Yours projects?

Comment: By "using a container object for those values". You should pass in a `Person` object. Or rather, you should just write `to_string()` for `Person` and not have a `printPersons()` method at all.

Comment: Yes, but how will be look like that container in upper example?

Comment: I suggest you learn about classes. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: If you want a quickfix, use a `String[]` instead of all those. In the long run you probably need to rethink your code design.

Comment: So, I should create new class Person, which fields will be all parameters, and call Person object to printPerson?

Comment: define a class with all that information and use that as parameter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a simple class that encapsulates all of those fields, and pass that to your original method.

```
public class Person {
  private final String name;
  private final String surname;
  private final String day;
  private final String car;
  private final String city;
  private final String petName;

  public Person(final String name, final String surname, final String day, final String car, final String city, final String petName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.day = day;
    this.car = car;
    this.city = city;
    this.petName = petName;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public String getSurname() {
    return this.surname;
  }

  public String getDay() {
    return this.day;
  }

  public String getCar() {
    return this.car;
  }

  public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
  }

  public String getPetName() {
    return this.petName;
  }
}
```

And your method call now becomes:

```
public void printPersons(Person person) {}
```

Comment: Maybe you just moved the problem with the many String arguments to the constructor?! Replace the constructor with a user friendly builder would be a good solution, I think.

Comment: Having many arguments to a constructor is not really a big deal imo. It's much worse if it's a public method doing that because it's impossible for the user of that method to anticipate what's going to happen, given that he supplies so many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is out of question that a container object (Person) should be used here. To make the construction of Person instances easier a inner class PersonBuilder is used, no constructor or setters are exposed.

```
    public final class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final String surname;
    private final String day;
    private final String car;

    // all the other attributes omitted

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // usage example
        Person person = Person.builder().name("Name").surname("Surname")
                .car("Tesla").day("Friday").build();

        person.toString();

    }

    // private constructor, only used by the PersonBuilder
    private Person(final PersonBuilder pb) {
        this.name = pb.name;
        this.surname = pb.surname;
        this.day = pb.day;
        this.car = pb.car;
    }

    public static PersonBuilder builder() {
        return new PersonBuilder();
    }

    public String toString() {

        return "return a nicely formatted String for printing, logging etc.";
    }

    /**
     * expose a nice, fluent API to construct Persons.
     */
    public static final class PersonBuilder {
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private String day;
        private String car;

        // use the static method Person.builder() to get an instance.
        private PersonBuilder() {
        }

        public PersonBuilder surname(final String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder name(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder day(final String day) {
            this.day = day;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonBuilder car(final String car) {
            this.car = car;
            return this;
        }

        public Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public String getCar() {
        return car;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for all solution. Sometimes I have the big problem to fully understand PMD message. Personally, I prefer the builder pattern.

Comment: `PersonBuilder` should pass itself to the `Person` constructor, to avoid the long method signature that PMD complains about.

Comment: @jaco0646 You are perfectly right, I changed this now. Also I added a static method in Person to get a PersonBuilder (Person.builder()) and made the constructor of PersonBuilder private.

Comment: I would remove all getter methods from `PersonBuilder`, to shorten the code and discourage clients from using the builder in place of `Person`.